# Accessing Amazon S3 resources using IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I found out Amazon S3 give me different IP address when I tried to access the same resources. 13.111.11.11 and 13.222.11.11. Do they point to the same server location or do they point to different server location. If a file get updated, does accessing it on the two different IP make a difference in terms if we want to get it first?

Answer (score 1):

You should always access Amazon S3 by using the provided DNS name (eg `my-bucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`).

There are many, many servers powering Amazon S3 so you should never cache nor use a particular IP address. Also, if you are using a DNS name that resolves to a particular bucket (like the example above), S3 requires the domain name to know which bucket to access (since an IP address alone is insufficient).

The [Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel) says:

> Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects in your S3 bucket in all regions ... Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES in all regions.

So, new files will always return the file, but updates might be subject to a short delay as the change is propagated between servers.

Comment: Potentially worth noting, the IP addresses returned by DNS queries for S3 resources do not point to individual "servers."  There are load balancers in front, and a multi-layered architecture distributed and replicated across multiple availability zones behind that... so even accessing via the same IP in the front does not correlate to accessing the same resources in the back.

Comment: But what if one need a specific IP address? For example, we have secured server that can access only websites that are whitelisted. However, since the server is old, it cannot add domains/URLs to the firewall, but only IP addresses. What one do in this case? I think AWS must have solution for this and ability to assign static IP address to the S3 bucket somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vitomir No, it is not possible to assign an IP address to an Amazon S3 bucket. You would need to whitelist the entire range of the Amazon S3 service. See: [Find the IP address ranges used by Amazon S3 | AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-find-ip-address-ranges)